# How do I select the latest rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I want to select the latest rows of a specific table that has 5 items in MySQL. 
The table looks like:

- id (auto increase)
- to
- from
- time stamp
- text

The data is something like:

```
|id | to     | from   | time stamp | text
| 1 | user01 | user02 | 2011-09-01 | text1
| 2 | user01 | user02 | 2011-09-02 | text2
| 3 | user02 | user01 | 2011-09-02 | text3
| 4 | user01 | user03 | 2011-09-03 | text4
| 5 | user01 | user04 | 2011-09-03 | text5
| 6 | user01 | user03 | 2011-09-04 | text6
| 7 | user03 | user01 | 2011-09-05 | text7
```

I want to `select * WHERE to = 'user01'` and the latest data (maybe by "id" or "time stamp"). The "from" can be numerous but each same "from" data can appear just once.

---

Anyway, the selected data will be:

```
| 2 | user01 | user02 | 2011-09-02 | text2
| 5 | user01 | user04 | 2011-09-03 | text5
| 6 | user01 | user03 | 2011-09-04 | text6
```

Could it be done?
Thanks for taking time reading my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM
      TableX AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT `from` AS f
        FROM TableX
        WHERE `to` = 'user01'
      ) AS df
    ON 
      t.id = ( SELECT tt.id
               FROM TableX AS tt
               WHERE tt.`to` = 'user01'
                 AND tt.`from` = df.f
               ORDER BY tt.`timestamp` DESC
               LIMIT 1
             )
```

---

It's better to avoid naming tables and fields with keywords like `to`, `from` and `timestamp`.

Comment: thanks for replying, your code do works! thanks a lot! cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE to = 'user01' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

...will give you the newest entry.

Comment: I think, that he want to get the newest entry for each combination of to and from.

Comment: yeah Alexander Sulfrian is right, this method I've tried and it will only get the "single" latest data, thanks for replying

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `SELECT DISTINCT user_from FROM table WHERE user_to='user1' ORDER BY id DESC`?

DISTINCT will only return ONE row for each user_from value.

Comment: your code is work, I've got 3 data just match the 3 different from user, but with some reason the data label is blank, I'll keep trying, thanks for replying

Comment: You could try `SELECT DISTINCT user_from AS custom_data_title FROM table ....`. Also, as ypercube noted, you should avoid field names like "from", as it's a keyword :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl
    WHERE to = 'user01'
    GROUP BY from
);
```

But I do not know if it matches your requirement, that each "from" could only appear once.

Comment: This should work, too, if the two orderings, via `id` and via `timestamp` are the same. Just needs adding `WHERE to='user01'` in the subquery `(SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl WHERE to='user01' GROUP BY to, from)`.

Comment: Oh, I missed the WHERE... Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like the latest row per unique `from` user:

```
SELECT `from`, MAX(`id`), `to` FROM `tablename` WHERE `to`='user01' GROUP BY `from`
```

(I think getting the MAX of id might be faster than MAX of time stamp)

Comment: your code works just fine, but I cant get the text data, thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

```
SELECT to, from, max(timestamp) FROM <table> WHERE to = 'user01' GROUP BY from
```

To get the associated text also you can also do it like this, but it is not very efficient

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE 
    CONCAT([to], [from], [timestamp]) 
    IN 
    (
     SELECT CONCAT([to], [from], MAX([timestamp])) FROM <table> 
     WHERE [to] = 'user01' GROUP BY [from]
    )
```

Comment: your code works just fine, but I cant get the text data, thanks for replying :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `to` = 'user01' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: this gives only single data, what I want is different from user with to = user01, but still, thanks for replying :)